# Describe the preimage of any point $(b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for $F(x, y) = (x+y,xy)$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I plotted the line and the hyperbola implied by the first and second coordinates respectively. I realize that the preimage can be

- Empty for $c > 0 \land b < c$
- Size one for $c = 0 \lor (b = c \land c > 0)$
- Size two for $c < 0 \lor b > c$.

But I need help actually writing down the expressions for each scenario. I would also appreciate knowing what course/area I should look into to get more practice with this type of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for solutions to the equation $f(x,y)=(b,c)$, i.e.

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x+y=b \\
xy=c
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Consider two cases

(1) $c=0$. Then $xy=0$ meaning either $x=0$ or $y=0$. The first equation then implies that either $y=b$ or $x=b$. Meaning for $c=0$ there are two solutions: $(0, b)$ and $(b,0)$.

(2) $c\neq 0$. Then $xy=c$ implies neither $x=0$ nor $y=0$. Therefore $y=c/x$ makes total sense. So in the first equation we get

$$x+y=b$$
$$x+c/x=b$$
$$x^2 + c=bx$$
$$x^2-bx+c=0$$

So all that is left is to solve this equation, which can have at most two solutions depending on $b,c$. Can you complete the calculations?

Comment: You can summarize both cases as the pre-image is the set $$F^{-1}((b,c))=\{(x,y) \, | \, x \text{ and } y \text{ are roots of } t^2-bt+c=0\}.$$